# How can I change port of lightswitch HTMLClient

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

When I run my light switch html client it is running in url
http://localhost:55305/HTMLClient/.

Like we do in aspnet application I want to change the the port 55305 to some thing else

How can I change running port of light switch HTMLClient.

Using lightswitch 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you're debugging and utilizing the IIS Express web server. To change the settings, make sure you've shut down Visual Studio, and shut down the development web server if it's still running (check for IIS Express in the notifications area, if it's there shut it down).

Then open your *ProjectName*Server csproj file and edit the value of **IISUrl** to be http://localhost:***YourPortNumber***/. Save the file, open up your LightSwitch solution and hit debug, it should use the chosen port.

Note that if the port is already in use, the web server will be unable to start up and you'll receive errors trying to view the page.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the **Server** project file, not the **Client** project file? I just created a blank LS project, and it's right there, under ProjectExtensions -> VisualStudio -> FlavorProperties -> WebProjectProperties.

Comment: You are correct sorry for the mistakes ,I can see  IISUrl  now.Thanks a lot Bobby J

Comment: No worries, with so many pieces it can be tricky to figure out exactly where to look.